# crash in presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER and/or GLES2VBVO::EnsureVerticesInited

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, crash

I am experiencing two random crashes, but they only seem to be occurring on the iPhone 4. All of our Android devices and any Apple device newer than an iPhone 4 does not crash. We recently started building for iOS, and have had working Android builds for over a year.

The iPhone 4 is on iOS 7.1.2
Unity is 4.5.5.f1 
Xcode is 5.1.1

The phone was on iOS 7.0, and upgrading to 7.1 did not help. We also tried a build with Unity 4.5.5p5 and the issue still persists.

Both Crashes have this at the top of the call stack of the thread:

```
gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart
```

One of the crashes is in DisplayManager.mm:

```
- (void)present
{
    if(surface.context != nil)
    {
        PreparePresentRenderingSurface(&surface, [[DisplayManager Instance] mainDisplay]->surface.context);

        EAGLContextSetCurrentAutoRestore autorestore(surface.context);
        GLES_CHK(glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, surface.systemColorRB));
        [surface.context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

        if(needRecreateSurface)
        {
            RenderingSurfaceParams params =
            {
                surface.msaaSamples, (int)requestedRenderingSize.width, (int)requestedRenderingSize.height,
                surface.use32bitColor, surface.use24bitDepth, surface.cvTextureCache != 0
            };
            [self recreateSurface:params];

            needRecreateSurface = NO;
            requestedRenderingSize = CGSizeMake(surface.targetW, surface.targetH);
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXB95.png)

The other is in the OpenGL library at:

```
GLES2VBO::EnsureVerticesInited(bool)
```

[Link to Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7NiG.png)

Comment: please: you can copy/paste almost anything from any IDE as plain text. Select the call stack, Cmd+C, paste it here. Images are hard, if not impossible, to read.

Comment: I added the function from DisplayManager.mm.
  
Once I get the other exception again, GLES2VBO::EnsureVerticesInited(bool),
I will post that assembly.

I also changed the images back to URL links so they can be viewed at native resolution. Not sure why they turned into those non-helpful thumbnails.

Comment: Oh, I did that. It's best to embed everything into the post because links may break eventually, and that would make the post less useful to others.

Comment: btw, try using xcode 6, 5 is largely outdated. You can install it side by side as well.

Comment: Hmm, tried xcode 6, and I get the exact same EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: If you get an OpenGL error code (such as 0x505 or something) you may be able to narrow down the cause via OpenGL's descriptions of error codes.

Comment: It looks like at the top of my stack there is this error for both exceptions :  gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart

@LearnCocos2D , any insights on to that?

Comment: Search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart